# Dynamically choosing class to inherit from C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write code in C# where i can inherit dynamically based on country with single line of code and not repeating as i am doing below

```
SubmitOrder : India
{
}

SubmitOrder : China
{
}

public class SubmitOrder : Italy
{
}
```

So what I want is to inherit from a generic class

What i want to do is something as below

```
public class SubmitOrder : InheritBasedOnCoutryIamIn
```

Comment: Nope. Can't do it (except by dynamically creating new class objects at runtime). You can, of course, refactor your application so that you don't have this problem. For example, you could use composition.

Comment: Aside from the dynamic extensions, C# is a statically-typed language. So, no.

Comment: The edit was unnecessary. We understand what you want to do. I recommend reading about [composition vs inheritance](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose)

Comment: no, and it would be wrong even if you could,  because  SubmitOrder IS A India.... doesn't make sense, there are likely way better ways to do what you want

Comment: What were you hoping to achieve by doing this? What functionality?

Comment: @john Are you referring to Nathalia's edit? How was that unnecessary?

Comment: @Austin I [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20329862) Nathalia's edit. I wouldn't have done that if I thought it unnecessary. I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51393066/2).

Comment: @john Oh, haha, I was gonna say.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to dynamically inherit a base class. You can use generic types like this and pass your country using constructor or property:

```
public class SubmitOrder<T>
{
    public Country { get; set; }

    public SubmitOrder(T country) => Country = country;
}
```

But in fact I think you are misunderstood about inheritance and base class. Your common methods and properties must be in base class and using inheritance you can customize and/or add some more functionality to those ones. May be you should have classes like this:

```
public class India: SubmitOrder
{
}

public class China: SubmitOrder
{
}

//...
```